# Finding Multiples of a number between a range [Java]

Tags: java, performance, numbers

We have been given a range **A<=B** and a number **M**. We have to find how many multiples of M lie in the given range.

My Solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ABC {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        long A = sc.nextLong();
        long B = sc.nextLong();
        long M = sc.nextLong();

        int res = 0;
        while(A<=B)
        {
            if(A%M==0)res++;
            A++;
        }
        System.out.println(res+"");
    }
    }
}
```

Now this is not very efficient. Please tell me how this problem can be solved in least amount of time.

Comment: What about `(B-A)/M`? If A and B should be considered into the range this should be handled additional. And also the other edge cases where M > B, M > (B-A), ...

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question regarding `(B-A)/M`. There is a possibility that A==B.... In that case B-A will always be divisible by M

Comment: Assume `A=10`, `B=23` and `M=5` the result (based on your code snippet) should be `3`. So `(23-10)/5` would give you `2` and as `10 is divisible by 5` you add one more.

Comment: Assume `A=5`, `B=10` and `M=3`. `(10-5)/3` gives us `1`. Neither 10 or 5 is divisible by 3... but correct answer should be 2... not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do it (after some more testing).

```
int r = (b/m - a/m) + (a % m == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

explanation

1. find the amount of multiples `m` between `a/m` and `b/m`
2. if `a` is a multiple of `m` add one more `(a % m == 0 ? 1 : 0)`

**small example PoC**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] pairs = {{10, 24}, {10, 25}, {11, 24}, {11, 25}, {10, 27}};
    int m = 5;
    for (int[] pair : pairs) {
        int a = pair[0];
        int b = pair[1];
        int r = (b/m - a/m) + (a % m == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.printf("a: %d  b: %d  result = %d  ", a, b, r);
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % m == 0) {
                System.out.print(" " + i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

**output**

```
a: 10  b: 24  result = 3   10 15 20
a: 10  b: 25  result = 4   10 15 20 25
a: 11  b: 24  result = 2   15 20
a: 11  b: 25  result = 3   15 20 25
a: 10  b: 27  result = 4   10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 3):

The smallest integer n1 such that n1*M ≥ A is n1=ceil(A/M), and the largest integer n2 such that n2*M ≤ B is n2=floor(B/M). The number of integers between n1 and n2 inclusive is max_of(n2−n1+1 ; 0).

Combining the above we have the answer:

max_of(floor(Z/X)−ceil(Y/X)+1 ; 0)

This is a somewhat standard problem in competitive programming :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
long A = sc.nextLong();
    long B = sc.nextLong();
    long M = sc.nextLong();

    if (M > A) {
        A = M;
    }
    if(M > B){
        System.out.println("0");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(  (((B-A)/M)+1) + "");
```

**Explanation :**

if 2 is first multiple than we dont need to check for 3, we have to add 2 to get next multiple so we dont need to traverse from first value to last and check if value is multiple or not, we just need to find first multiple and than number of steps it will take to reach last number means our B by adding M to A.

Answer (score 0):

This works great.

```
int multiples = 0;
    for(int i = x; i<=y; i++){
     if(i%z==0)
      multiples++;
    }
```

As long as y>x, if that isn't always true just add an additional if statement that checks if y>x or x>y. :)